# Definir largura e altura em caixa de texto

Tags: python, tkinter

Para ampliar conhecimento, decidi iniciar uma nova linguagem de programação, Python, e travei na seguinte situação, tenho uma tela com alguns elementos e uma caixa de texto do tipo `Entry`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para definir a caixa de texto, usei o seguinte código:

```
self.form = Entry(self.frame2)
self.form.pack()
```

Dei uma pesquisada básica, no entanto o pessoal troca `Entry` por `Text` e define `width` e `heigth`. Tentei utilizar, porém no momento em que utilizo `form.get()` para capturar o texto, aparece um erro:

> TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1'

Gostara de saber como faço para definir largura e altura do `Entry`?

Comment: Tag errada...o problema não é com o python, mas com o modulo Tkinter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O  [`tkinter.Entry`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) só permite definir a largura. Como alternativa é usado o [`tkinter.Text`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) que permite fazer essas alterações.

> TypeError: `get()` missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1'

Diferente do [`tkinter.Entry.get`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.get-method) que retorna todo o conteúdo do `Entry`, o [`tkinter.Text.get`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.get-method) retorna os caracteres que estiverem dentro de um intervalo, *start* e *end*, se *end* for omitido, apenas um caractere é retornado. A mensagem indica que você deve informar pelo menos um argumento, *start*.

Para pegar todo o conteúdo, faça assim:

```
conteudo = texto.get(1.0, END)
```

Veja um exemplo:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Calculadora')
root.geometry('300x300')

texto = Text(root, height = 4, width = 15)
texto.insert(INSERT, 'foo bar')
texto.pack()

conteudo = texto.get(1.0, END)
print (conteudo)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: O que representa o 1.0?

Comment: @seamusd O primeiro caractere.

Comment: Validado a resposta! Abraços.

Answer (score 0):

Poderia usar o place dessa forma passando os paramentos como no exemplo:

```
from tkinter import*

janela = Tk ()

janela.geometry("300x400")

#criando o Entry()

E = Entry(janela)

**# função place alterar posição do frame na tela relativo x e y e relwidth a largura e relheight a altura**

E.place(relx = 0.1, rely = 0.1,relwidth = 0.8,relheight=0.11)

janela.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

Para ter uma caixa de texto que seja possível aumentar a altura, você precisa usar o `tkinter.tix`, é uma extensão do `tkinter`, nele há inúmeros outros objetos visuais, o `LabelEntry` se me lembro, permite a entrada de texto e da pra aumentar a sua largura e sua altura.